# Django Custom Error Handlers in Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, custom-error-pages

I have custom 404 and 500 error handlers setup in django and they work in development, but with Apache they just show the default apache  Internal Server Error page, even for 404 errors.

Here is my urls.py:

```
handler400 = 'views.error400'
handler403 = 'views.error403'
handler404 = 'views.error404'
handler500 = 'views.error500'
```

I've read of many ways to set up custom error pages in apache, but all of the approaches I tried with django did not work.  What is the correct way to set this up for Apache/mod_wsgi and Django?

Do I remove those lines from my urls.py and add some lines to my apache.conf?

What lines should be added to apache.conf as I'm not sure how to access views from the apache configuration file and the normal urls.py routing for Django is not working for the custom error pages since as I suspect Apache is intercepting the requests and providing it's own pages.

I just want to use my templates for my custom error pages (which include inheriting from a base template).

How can I achieve this, I can't find a decent answer anywhere?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried editting the Apache config to add `ErrorDocument 500 /templates/500.html` and such but it did not work.

I currently have the error page in my templates directory, they each inherit from a base template.  Also, they each have their own view to handle the responses.

But no matter what I do, removing those lines from urls.py, adding stuff to apache config, etc.  I can't get anything but the typical Internal Server Error apache page to display on any error, even one's that aren't 500 errors.

What can I do to get this working?  Worked fine on the django development server, but as soon as apache was thrown into the mix I can't get it to work using either apache or django, I must be missing something but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove those lines from `urls.py`. Django will look up to your templates to get those.

Just put `404.html` and `500.html` files into `your_app/templates/` directory.

Comment: I have those files in my templates directory.  If I remove those lines from my urls.py, what do I add to my Apache config to make them work?

Comment: So add something like `ErrorDocument 404 /templates/404.html`?  And the same for 500.html and even 403.html

Comment: Django router will take care of that, you don't have to change Apache config.

Comment: But if I removed those lines from urls.py how will Django router take care of it ?  I just gave it a try and still get the default Apache pages.  I'm a bit confused here about how Django could handle it when I just removed those lines from urls.py.  It seems that Apache needs to handle it as it is giving me it's default error pages.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have TEMPLATE_DIRS setting set? You should have those templates in that directory.

Comment: Yes they are in that directory.  The templates are in the right place, but without those lines in urls.py the views are never called.  And with the lines, the apache error pages are getting priority it seems.  So I don't see how deleting those lines in urls.py will make the custom pages work without any changes to the apache.conf.  As there is nothing telling the server to use those templates when encountering a 404/500 error.

Comment: I tried following your instructions, and nothing has changed.  I believe I need to change my apache.conf to what I stated a few comments ago...  `ErrorDocument 404 /templates/404.html`  Only confusion I have is that those error templates inerhit from a base template, and if I call them from Apache will it properly render the template and the inheritance?

Comment: I tried editting the apache config and no luck there either.  Right now I have a handler view for 400, 403, 404, and 500.  Each has it's own template in templates/ folder. In urls.py I have the `handler404 = 'views.error404'` lines still, I tried removing them but made no difference.  WIth or without them I can't get anything but the typical Apache Internal Server Error page to come up.

Comment: I'd suggest you to set `DEBUG = True` for a second and check if the errors come from Django or Apache config.

Comment: Okay, well to me right now it seems that Apache is intercepting the errors before they get to Django.